# How to use the new M7 motion co-processor in an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerometer, core-motion, apple-m7

My question could sound simple or stupid, but I just want to make things clear. I'm using accelerometer in an app, and I want to know how can I use the new iPhone 5S **M7** motion co-processor, at the moment I'm receiving accelerometer data using `CoreMotion.framework` method `- (void)startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue withHandler:(CMAccelerometerHandler)handler;`, is it enough? This is an universal approach (good for devices which doesn't have M7 co-processor)? Or I must do something else? Where can I read and learn about how to use the new M7 processor in an app? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- M7 co-processor will enable applications to be `aware of what type of
  movement` the user is experiencing, such as driving, walking, running
  or sleeping. then Application could be the ability to do indoor tracking and mapping.
- The Apple M7 co-processor collects, processes and stores `sensor data`
  even if the device is **asleep**, and applications can retrieve data when
  the device is powered up again. This will reduce power draw of the
  device and save battery life

For more info [refer this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M7)

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not certain, but it seems pretty obvious that the M7 would be used to implement CoreMotion on devices that have it, just like the A7 CPU would be used to provide the computing foundation on devices that have it.

I very much doubt there is anything you need to do to enable it; you just get better data I guess.